# Visiting UK shortly before Tier 2 application

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm planning on (or rather, my employer is planning on) making a Tier 2 application for me to work in the UK. They already have the certificate of sponsorship and all that's left is for me to show up at the visa application centre with my docs. However, shortly before the biometrics appointment I plan on making a trip to the UK for a quick vacation (I currently live in France). I have a Canadian passport, so I don't need a visa to enter the UK as a visitor, but (1) would this negatively impact my chances at getting the tier 2 visa and (2) could I run into potential issues at the border when I try to enter for holiday?

Answer (score 1):

Under the circumstances, that you are a non-visa national, Canada, with residence in France, a visit to the UK is not likely to adversely affect the Tier 2 decisionmaking process. Actually, with all of the plans underway and the COS issued, it would make sense that you might want to be in the UK for a short time to sort out accommodation and other logistics in advance of the transition.